# How to use Metal to draw shapes on a rendered image without redrawing the whole texture?

Tags: metal, metalkit

I'm trying to understand GPU image processing with Metal and have successfully manipulated and rendered images onto a screen.
I currently render my manipulated image by using a custom vertex and fragment shader that takes in the size of the texture and the screen, and then resizes it to the correct aspect ratio. It is redrawn using MTKViewDelegate. This code is shown below

```
guard let currentRenderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor,
            let currentDrawable = view.currentDrawable,
            let renderPipelineState = renderPipelineState,
            let encoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: currentRenderPassDescriptor)
        else {
            semaphore.signal()
            return
        }

        encoder.pushDebugGroup("RenderFrame")
        encoder.setRenderPipelineState(renderPipelineState)

        encoder.setVertexBytes(&textureOccupiedDimensions, length:  MemoryLayout<vector_int2>.size, index: 0)
        encoder.setVertexBytes(&viewportSize, length:  MemoryLayout<vector_int2>.size, index: 1)
        encoder.setFragmentTexture(texture, index: 0)
        encoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangleStrip, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 4, instanceCount: 1)
        encoder.popDebugGroup()

        encoder.endEncoding()

        commandBuffer.addScheduledHandler { [weak self] (buffer) in
            guard let unwrappedSelf = self else { return }

            unwrappedSelf.didRenderTexture(texture, withCommandBuffer: buffer, device: device)
            unwrappedSelf.semaphore.signal()
        }

        commandBuffer.present(currentDrawable) // schedules display at next possible refresh point
        commandBuffer.commit()
```

I now want to draw some primitive shapes (lines, circles, etc) on my rendered image that don't require knowledge of the texture layout of the image underneath, but am not sure what's the best way to approach this challenge. These shapes will have to update each time the image is refreshed as well. I understand how to use compute encoders to copy the whole texture while altering certain points, but I don't know if this is the most efficient way to accomplish this. Any advice would be much appreciated!